# Algorithm for dividing works into threads by priority

Tags: algorithms, multi-tasking

**TL;DR**

Is there an existing algorithm for dividing `W` works each with priority `P` using `T` threads? If there isn't, could you direct me to a solution?

**Expansion**

given:

`W` - amount of works [0,Infinity)

`P(w)` - priority [1,10]

`T` - available threads [0,Infinity).

`N(w)` - "neighbors" of a work `w` in its thread

There is an inverse proportionality between `P(w)` to `N(w)`:

$$
{\displaystyle P(w)={\frac {factor}{N(w)}}}
$$

If there are more available threads than works, each work can have its own thread. If there are more works than available threads, then multiple works have to share a single thread. The more a work is prioritize, the less neighbors it gets in a thread allocated for them.

*Example#1*

given
$$
P(w_1) = 10,P(w_2) = 8,P(w_3) = 5,P(w_4) = 3
$$
$$
T=3
$$

Should result:

$$
N(w_1) = 0,N(w_2) = 0,N(w_3) = 1,N(w_4) = 1
$$

*Example#2*

given
$$
P(w_1) = 10,P(w_2) = 8,P(w_3) = 5,P(w_4) = 3
$$
$$
T=2
$$

Should result:

$$
N(w_1) = 0,N(w_2) = 2,N(w_3) = 2,N(w_4) = 2
$$

There aren't more constraint.

The following options are valid:

- a work `w1` with priority `10` can have a neighbor `w2` with priority `1` in the same thread I.E. when there is only one available thread.
- a work `w1` with priority `10` and a work `w2` with priority `1` can have zero neighbors, I.E. where they are the only works, and there are two available threads.

Comment: Sounds like the scheduling task a CPU does

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by "neighbors" in this context.  What properties do you want the division to have?

Comment: @D.W. "what is meant by 'neighbors'" - if there are more available threads than works, each work can have its own thread. if there are more works than available threads, then multiple works have to share a single thread. "What properties do you want the division to have" - we need to distribute the works in a way that a more prioritize work, would get less neighbors in the thread allocated for them.

Comment: Rather than leaving clarifications in the comments, please [edit] your post to make it clear what you are asking, and make it read well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  We don't want people to have to read the comments to understand the question.  That said, I still don't think the requirements are very clear or precise.  For example: Is it possible to have two "works" with the same number of neighbors, but one has a slightly higher priority than the other?

Comment: OK sir. I will fix all you asked soon

Comment: Sorry for the delay. a war is taking place in my region. please tell me if the edit is sufficient.

Comment: No, the edits doesn't adequately answer my question.  We need a full specification of what the output should be in all cases, or what conditions the output must satisfy.  An example is not a substitute for a specification.  Without that, I doubt that the question can be answered.  Sorry to hear about the situation in your region, how terrifying.